# Is it possible return comma seperated arrays? (not a single array)

Tags: php, arrays

I'm setting up a function like this:

```
function return_my_arrays() {
    $the_array = array(
        array(
            'foo' => '1',
            'bar' => '12'
        ),
        array(
            'foo' => '41',
            'bar' => '512'
        ),
        array(
            'foo' => 'b1',
            'bar' => 'a'
        ),
    );

    return implode( ',', $the_array );
}
```

I need to return the 2nd level arrays comma separated from this function. But this code doesn't work.

These arrays will be used in another multidimensional array and will be extended. directly returning $the_array won't work for me.

Comment: Wouldn't `return $the_array` do the trick?

Comment: '"These arrays will be used in another multidimensional array and will be extended". you should consider using the `array_merge_recursive` built-in function instead: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Comment: "comma separated arrays" is not a thing. Please be more clear? Arrays are arrays, there are lists of objects. String can contain comma separated values though.

Comment: I think it would work with foreach loop if there is a way to continue after returning something.

Comment: @SohanZaman could you improve your question? , I think I still do not get what you want to accomplish, regards.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help you out , maybe what you need is:

```
function return_my_arrays() {
            $the_array = array(
                array(
                    'foo' => '1',
                    'bar' => '12'
                ),
                array(
                    'foo' => '41',
                    'bar' => '512'
                ),
                array(
                    'foo' => 'b1',
                    'bar' => 'a'
                ),
            );

        $commaSeparated = '';
        foreach($the_array as $level2Array)
        {
           $commaSeparated .= $level2Array.',';
        }
        return $commaSeparated; 
    }
```

Comment: $level2Array is an array, you cannot concatenate it with strings just like that

Comment: @DenisMysenko What? `$the_array` is the array. `$level2Array` is the array split up.

Comment: Yes, i have tried this method but it didn't work. Because arrays doesn't attach to strings.

Comment: @Loko $level2Array is an array too, one of the second dimension arrays (there are three in total). You cannot merge array with string. You have to parse (with foreach, for instance) the second level array too.

Comment: @DenisMysenko Ok well Im really confused today.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to loop around your array to fetch the inner array - so you can manipulate it.

Something like this should suffice;

```
function return_my_arrays() {
    $the_array = array(
        array(
            'foo' => '1',
            'bar' => '12'
        ),
        array(
            'foo' => '41',
            'bar' => '512'
        ),
        array(
            'foo' => 'b1',
            'bar' => 'a'
        ),
    );
  $return = array();
  foreach($the_array as $inner_array) {
     $return[] = implode(",", $inner_array);
  }
  return implode(",", $return);
}
```

https://eval.in/301546

Answer (score 0):

[array_map](http://php.net/array_map) allows you to do it with no loops

```
return implode(',', array_map(function ($entry) {
  return $entry['foo'].",".$entry['bar'];
}, $the_array)); // 1,12,41,512,b1,a
```

https://eval.in/301662

Answer (score -1):

I think this is not possible with the way php works. But I have found a dirty solution for this.

I'm calling 'n' arrays from the function like this:

```
array(
    return_my_arrays()[0],
    return_my_arrays()[1],
)
```

I don't know if it's a good practice or not, but this does what I really need.

Comment: Touché. Tested somewhere and hadn't worked. Edit your answer so I can remove the downvote

Comment: I think you tested directly so it didn't work. I have already said that I need it in another array. see my edits. It's working this way.